# ora-01422 error in SELECT INTO statements

Tags: oracle, plsql, select-into, ora-01422

I have one row in my Company_Person_all view named by 'YENER UZUN' in EMPLOYEE_NAME column (I already want only one result). When I send parameter to this function (fname, instead of using 'YENER UZUN') I encounter

```
ORA-01422:exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows ...
```

What should I do to prevent this error? Also when I write the code below ('YENER UZUN', instead of fname) it's ok it doesn't give me an error.

```
FUNCTION Get_Calistigi_Santiye_By_Fname(fname IN varchar2)
    RETURN varchar2 
IS
    temp_ varchar2(100);
BEGIN
    select free_field6
    into   temp_
    from   company_person_all
    where  employee_name = 'YENER UZUN';

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(temp_);
    RETURN temp_;
END;
```

Comment: That shouldn't happen.  How are you calling the function and passing in the `fname` value?

Comment: BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line('something': '||company_person_api.Get_Calistigi_Santiye_By_Fname('YENER UZUN'));
END;  /* like this */

Comment: AND this code returns only one row to me ...

select * from Company_Person where employee_name ='YENER UZUN';

Comment: Debug it - change the procedure to loop though the returned rows and write out their employee_names and ROWIDs or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing 'fname' parameter name to 'xyz'. 'fname'  was being used a RECORD instance name by other procedures and functions in the package.
So that when i changed parameter name the error instantly fixed.

Comment: I, atleast dont know about any global paramter in Oracle called `fname` .

Comment: this is an ERP system based on Oracle, named IFS. I did not understand why it solved my problem exactly. But changing parameter name is not a joke , it solved this error.

Comment: Dont follow that you are not sure about. It might help you now but somewhere else it would hurt. try my solution and check if that works.

Comment: Your function doesn't use `fname` so it is not clear how that name collision could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, Using a `cursor` instead of `select .. into` is a shortcut to avoid *ORA-01422* with a proper `order by`(`asc` [*default*] / `desc`) clause due to which of the records prefer for your business logic(*last* or *first* record ) as in the following :

```
FUNCTION Get_Calistigi_Santiye_By_Fname( fname company_person_all.employee_name%type )
    RETURN company_person_all.free_field6%type 
IS
    temp_ company_person_all.free_field6%type;
BEGIN
  for c in
   (
    select free_field6 ff6
      from company_person_all
     where employee_name = fname --> 'YENER UZUN'
     order by work_date_time
   )
   loop
    temp_ :=  c.ff6;
   end loop;    
    dbms_output.put_line(temp_);

    RETURN temp_;
END;
```